# Хелперы в Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Зачем нужны хелперы в Ruby on Rails? Почему нельзя определить их в application_controller?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Дело в том что, да, методы помощника (helper) будут доступны не столько в контроллере сколько в представлении, т.е. это его методы, и создан он скорее да разгрузится представление от громоздкого кода. Чтобы методы стали доступны в контроллере, нужно объявлять помощник там принудительно. В случае, если вы будете воплощать методы помощника явно в контроллере и в представлении, вы, как верно заметил, Фатбель, просто сделаете код нечитаемым. А вообще если говорить именно за "стезю рельс", то более оптимальная схема такая:

- контроллер - обрабатывает данные входного запроса и пропускает нужные параметры (см. params_permit);
- модель - в подавляющем большинстве случаев описывает требования к полям таблицы в БД (см. validates), связи между таблицами (см. belongs_to, has_many/one) и выборки (см. scope) данных из таблиц по условиям. Могут также быть модели без привязки к конкретной таблице, напр. абстрактные модели. В сем случае, свойства оной просто задают некоторую общую основу для моделей наследников.
- представление - предоставляет описание или точнее схему того, что конечным пользователь увидит в результате своего запроса. Представления обычно описываются шаблонами erb, haml, slim и т.д.

Дополнительно, желательно (а на деле часто необходимо) иметь:

- служба (service) - позволяет разгрузить контроллер от бизнес-логики, каждая служба обычно представляет какую-либо операцию над моделями с возможным привлечением иных служб. Службы можно писать руками, а можно использовать бисер [services](https://github.com/krautcomputing/services).
- украситель (decorator) - позволяет разгрузить модель, а зачастую и помощники, от избыточной логики представления, например, от часто вызываются в представлении при отображении записи методов, которые обычно преобразуют для вывода какие-либо данные записи. Тут обычно используется бисер [draper](https://github.com/drapergem/draper).
- сериализёр (выпущик, serializer) - позволяет разгрузить контроллер и модель от бизнес-логики, и выборки, которая необходима конечному пользователю и запрашиваемая через api-вызовы (имеется ввиду внешняя сериализация). Обычно используется бисер [active_model_serializers](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers).

Comment: Модель может быть не связана с БД. Сравнительно редкое явление, но бывает.

Comment: @D-side да, конечно, напр.абстрактные модели =)

Comment: Например, да. А ещё бывают модели, представляющие представление (ой) из БД. Или вовсе другие сущности, например, процессы ОС, ветки git. В какой-то мере понятие БД можно натянуть и на них, но это только уточнит, что понимается под БД в контексте архитектуры.

Comment: @D-side ну в модель можно засунуть все что угодно, но это тоже будет не rails-стиль =)

Comment: Не будет. Rails Core даже [`ActiveModel::Model`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Model.html) [добавили](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/5253) для таких случаев.

Comment: @D-side Я всё-таки думаю, что не все что добавили, rails-стиль, и не всё что не добавили им не является.

Comment: Вывод: общепринятого Rails-стиля не существует и мы сейчас с вами рассуждаем ни о чём :}

Comment: @D-side Отнюдь, мы с вами очень хорошо и успешно порассуждали о вкусовщине =)

Answer (score 1):

Их можно определить и там через helper_method. Только это целесообразно для очень узкого круга хелперов, которые работают буквально на всех страницах. Иначе это загаживание контролера и ни разу не "Rails way".